# How to move element with your finger, but from the position where it is?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I wanted to move something, in this case it's button, on y axis using finger, but every time i slide my finger, it teleports to 0.0 and starts moving from there. Here is the code i'm using to do it.

```kotlin
var x : Double? = 0.0
var y : Double? = 0.0

main_page.setOnTouchListener{view , event->
    when (event.action){
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            x = view.x.toDouble() - event.rawX
            y = view.y.toDouble() - event.rawY
            true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            button.animate()
                .y(event.rawY + y!!.toFloat())
                .setDuration(0)
                .start()
            true
        }else -> {
            true
        }
    }
}
```

It's not fault of the x and y set to 0.0 at the start. (I already tried changing it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ACTION_DOWN is setting x,y based on container's x,y and then a different view, button, is moved. Just change how x,y are init.

By the way, you don't need to animate view's y position, you can just set it.

In case you want a touch anywhere in the container to move the button, you would do something like this:

```
var x: Double = 0.0
var y: Double = 0.0 

main_page.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            x = button.x.toDouble() - event.rawX
            y = button.y.toDouble() - event.rawY
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            button.y = event.rawY + y.toFloat()
        }
    }

    true
}
```

If you want the button to move only when touch starts in the button itself, use `button.setOnTouchListener{...}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I have one more question, do you maybe know, how to change it, so it will work when i touch anything ?

Comment: You need to set the `OnTouchListener` to the surface you want to respond to finger movements. If you want the whole screen to do it, set it to the main container. Have in mind some other component may be consuming the touch event, though. A view with an `onClickListener` or something else.